# urllib2 python (Transfer-Encoding: chunked)

Tags: python, urllib2, chunked, transfer-encoding

I used the following python code to download the html page:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(current_URL)
msg = response.read()  
print msg
```

For a page such as [this one](http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichJuriJudi.do?oldAction=rechJuriJudi&idTexte=JURITEXT000024053954&fastReqId=660326373&fastPos=1), it opens the url without error but then prints only part of the html-page!

In the following lines you can find the http headers of the html-page. I think the problem is due to  "Transfer-Encoding: chunked".

It seems urllib2 returns only the first chunk! I have difficulties reading the remaining chunks. How I can read the remaining chunks?

```
Server: nginx/1.0.5
Date: Wed, 27 Feb 2013 14:41:28 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: route=c65b16937621878dd49065d7d58047b2; Path=/
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=EE18E813EE464664EA64086D5AE9A290.tpdjo13v_3; Path=/
Pragma: No-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store,max-age=0
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Language: fr
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that if I Accept-Language header is specified than server doesn't drop TCP connection, otherwise it does.

```
curl -H "Accept-Language:uk,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,ru;q=0.4" -v 'http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichJuriJudi.do?oldAction=rechJuriJudi&idTexte=JURITEXT000024053954&fastReqId=660326373&fastPos=1'
```