# How to download chunked data with Pythons urllib2

Tags: python, download, urllib2, chunked, transfer-encoding

I'm trying to download a large file from a server with Python 2:

```
req = urllib2.Request("https://myserver/mylargefile.gz")
rsp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
data = rsp.read()
```

The server sends data with "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" and I'm only getting some binary data, which cannot be unpacked by gunzip.

Do I have to iterate over multiple read()s? Or multiple requests? If so, how do they have to look like?

Note: I'm trying to solve the problem with only the Python 2 standard library, without additional libraries such as urllib3 or requests. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

From the python documentation on urllib2.urlopen:

> One caveat: the read() method, if the size argument is omitted or
>   negative, may not read until the end of the data stream; there is no
>   good way to determine that the entire stream from a socket has been
>   read in the general case.

So, read the data in a loop:

```
req = urllib2.Request("https://myserver/mylargefile.gz")
rsp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
data = rsp.read(8192)
while data:
   # .. Do Something ..
   data = rsp.read(8192)
```

Comment: I'm under the impression, that this works to download only files, that are not sent with transfer-encoding=chunked.

Comment: Hmm, you're right.  I saw a similar question with no answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115606/urllib2-python-transfer-encoding-chunked Sorry, I'm not sure how to get past it.  The only answer used curl.

Comment: OK, I'll try curl, which is a little bit cumbersome with login cookies compared to Python, but better than nothing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, the following worked for me - a while back:

```
data = ''
chunk = rsp.read()
while chunk:
    data += chunk
    chunk = rsp.read()
```

Each `read` reads one chunk - so keep on reading until nothing more's coming.
Don't have documenation ready supporting this...yet.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me:

    content = ''
    while True:
        chunk = rsp.read()
        if not chunk
            break
        content += chunk
    f.write(content)

Comment: `does not work` unfortunately is a very un-helpful statement :) Is there still content missing?

Comment: Sorry: "does not work" in the sense of "exactly like before". I.e. the data is not complete and cannot be read by gunzip. I assume, that urllib2 just does not support chunked transfer-encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

I found that "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" often appears with "Content-Encoding: 
gzip".

So maybe we can get the compressed content and unzip it.

It works for me.

```py
import urllib2
from StringIO import StringIO
import gzip

req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header('Accept-encoding', 'gzip, deflate')
rsp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
if rsp.info().get('Content-Encoding') == 'gzip':
    buf = StringIO(rsp.read())
    f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buf)
    data = f.read()
```