# Using urllib2 to fetch plain text, result isn't full

Tags: python, jenkins, python-requests, urllib2

I'm writing a python script to parse jenkins job results. I'm using urllib2 to fetch consoleText, but the file that I receive isn't full. The code to fetch the file is:

```
data = urllib2.urlopen('http://<server>/job/<jobname>/<buildid>/consoleText')
lines = data.readlines()
```

And the number of lines I get is 2306, while the actual number of lines in the console log is 37521. I can check that buy fetching the file via `wget`:

```
$ wget 'http://<server>/job/<jobname>/<buildid>/consoleText'
$ wc -l consoleText
37521
```

Why does urlopen not give me the full result?

**UPDATE:**

Using `requests` (as suggested by @svrist) instead of `urllib2` doesn't have such a problem, so I'm switching to it. My new code is:

```
data = requests.get('http://<server>/job/<jobname>/<buildid>/consoleText')
lines = [l for l in data.iter_lines()]
```

But I still have no idea why `urllib2.urlopen` doesn't work properly.

Comment: Not to be that guy, but everybody will say: "use requests"

Comment: Do you think there might be a maximum number of items you can request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jenkins build log is returned using a [chunked encoding response](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.6.1).

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Based on a couple of [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24393797/172599) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15115606/172599), it seems like `urllib2` does not handle the entire response and as you've observed, only returns the first chunk.

I also recommend using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) package.